# Adjusting Text background transparency

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, plot, transparency

I'm trying to put some text with a background on a matplotlib figure, with the text and background both transparent.  The following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(np.linspace(1,0,1000))
t = plt.text(0.03,.95,'text',transform=ax.transAxes,backgroundcolor='0.75',alpha=.5)
plt.show()
```

makes the text semi-transparent relative to the text's background, but the background isn't at all transparent relative to the line it obscures in the figure.

```
t.figure.set_alpha(.5)
```

and

```
t.figure.patch.set_alpha(.5)
```

also don't do the trick.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `alpha` passed to `plt.text()` will change the transparency of the text font. To change the background you have to change the `alpha` using `Text.set_bbox()`:

```
t = plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'text', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=30)
t.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='red'))
#changed first dict arg from "color='red'" to "facecolor='red'" to work on python 3.6
```

To remove the border of the text box, as suggested in the comment of @halt9k, you can use `.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0))`.

[image]

Comment: You can also do `props = dict(...)` and `ax.text(... bbox=props)`

Comment: Also to remove edge, `.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0))`