# Transparent background with matplotlib's set_title()

Tags: python, matplotlib, transparency, alpha-transparency

I need to draw a title for a plot using [set_title()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title), where its background shows with some degree of transparency.

I've tried three methods (one taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698794/1391441)) but none seems to work. They either make the font of the text or the edges transparent, but not the background itself.

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='k', linestyle='--', lw=0.5,
        zorder=1)

# Method 1
ax.set_title("Title", x=0.5, y=0.92, fontsize=13, alpha=0.2,
             bbox=dict(facecolor='none'))

# Method 2
# ax.set_title("Title", x=0.5, y=0.92, fontsize=13,
#              bbox=dict(facecolor='none', alpha=0.2))

# Method 3
# t = ax.set_title("Title", x=0.5, y=0.92, fontsize=13)
# t.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='none', alpha=0.2, edgecolor='k'))

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there. The issue is that you have `facecolor='none'`, so even with an `alpha` set, there is nothing to make transparent, and you don't see the background at all.

You can change this by setting `facecolor='white'`, for example, modifying your "Method 2":

```
ax.set_title("Title", x=0.5, y=0.92, fontsize=13,
             bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5))
```

[image]

This has the side-effect of also making the black border transparent too.

A way to fix that issue is to explicitly define the `facecolor` and `edgecolor` as `(R,G,B,A)` tuples, and make sure the `edgecolor` has `alpha=1`:

```
ax.set_title("Title", x=0.5, y=0.92, fontsize=13,
             bbox=dict(facecolor=(1,1,1,0.5),edgecolor=(0,0,0,1)))
```

[image]